# Upgraded to 16.10 and lost the internet

Tags: networking, dns

Total newcomer here, so please talk to me like a 8 year old

I recently upgraded to 16.10 and lost my internet connection. As far as I can tell, something is wrong with my dns

Please help

This is what I have tried so far, without any result:

```
Ping google.com - result: name or service not known. 

Ping 8.8.8.8 - result: 31 packets transmitted, 31 received, 0% packet loss, time 30046ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 23.660/24.377/24.820/0.373 ms

Uname -a result:
Linux Cassandra 4.8.0-46-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 31 13:57:14 utc 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

ls -a /etc/resolv.conf result:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Apr 16 13:21 /etc/resolv.conf -> ..run/resolvconf/resolv.conf

cat /etc/resolv.conf result:
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver (3) generated by resolvcobf(8) 
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
```

nameserver 192.168.1.1 nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4 nameserver 8.8.8.8

Comment: Press CTRL + ALT + t. This opens a terminal. Enter `ping google.com`. After a while, press CTRL + C. What is the output? Edit your question and paste the output of the `ping` into it. Now do the same for `ping 8.8.8.8`.

Comment: Ping google.com - result: name or service not known.   Ping 8.8.8.8 - result: 31 packets transmitted, 31 received, 0% packet loss, time 30046ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 23.660/24.377/24.820/0.373 ms

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, pings by number work correctly. Pings by name do not so we suspect that you are correct that it is a DNS issue. I recommend that you set your own DNS in Network Manager as shown here:

[image]

Right-click the Network Manager icon and select 'Edit Connections.' Select either your ethernet or wireless, as needed and click the IPv4 Settings tab.

After making the changes as above, save and close. Reboot.

Any improvement?

It appears that, despite the warning to not edit `/etc/resolv.conf` by hand, someone has done so. Please run:

```
sudo resolvconf -u
```

Reboot. Any change?

Comment: No, unfortunately this has changed nothing. What's next?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` And also: `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: No change - what's next?