# DNS Update on Ubuntu 16.10 How do I do this?

Tags: dns

I need to manually update the DNS settings on my Ubuntu 16.10 desktop.  It is not a server.  This is a part of working with Ubuntu I do not know or understand well.  I have recently had to switch to using vpn to connect to our setup.  I've done that with AnyConnect and am connected.  But changing the dns is giving me trouble.

I need to update to these two IPs.

```
1.2.3.4 as the primary/preferred/first address
1.2.3.2 as the secondary/alternate/second address
```

I am "*assuming*" that these need to be in my /etc/resolv.conf file?  Maybe /etc/hosts ??

I tried changing the Network Connection using what I found in this article: [Upgraded to 16.10 and lost the internet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911054/upgraded-to-16-10-and-lost-the-internet).  But, that did not change my /etc/resolv.conf file

Would anyone be able to tell me how to do this?  Thank you for the assist.
I wasn't able to tag this with ubuntu 16.10

Comment: See [What is the proper way to change the DNS IP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2321/what-is-the-proper-way-to-change-the-dns-ip)

Comment: Thanks, steeldriver.  That seemed to work "this time".    I did that before, but maybe I did not hit the Save button.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this following instructions from a page posted by steeldriver yesterday :

```
[See What is the proper way to change the DNS IP? – steeldriver][1]
```

I almost had it on my own, I was not SAVE-ing my changes in the Network Connections section when I first tried this - before creating this thread.

Thanks all for the info though.  Much appreciated.